# How to set the step of plotting by one of axes in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I have a data such as list of points x,y,z. I added interpolation by splines as
  `f = Interpolation[{#[[1 ;; 2]], #[[3]]} & /@ data, Method -> "Spline"]`
And after all I try to plot

```
`Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 10000, 10000000}, {y, 10, 50}, Mesh -> 15, 
MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.0011}, 
PlotRangePadding -> {0.001, 0.0003}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7], 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
AxesStyle -> {Black, Black, Black}], 
Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[.016], Point[data]}]]`
```

Can't post image.
I use such data as
    `data = {{10000, 10, 0.000000208191701}, {10000, 20, 0.000000416383402}, {10000, 30, 0.00000066886188}, {10000, 40,0.000000832854501}, {10000, 50, 0.000001040870809}, {100000, 10,0.000002081829313}, {100000, 20, 0.000004163483234}, {100000, 30,0.000006245400245}, {100000, 40, 0.000008327229558}, {100000, 50,0.000010409058871}, {1000000, 10, 0.000020818731618}, {1000000,20, 0.000041636761666}, {1000000, 30, 
    0.000062455405588}, {1000000, 40, 0.00008327361103}, {1000000, 50,
     0.000104092254952},{10000000, 10, 0.000208475750285}, {10000000,
     20, 0.000416951237469}, {10000000, 30, 
    0.000625426900044}, {10000000, 40, 0.000833902387228}, {10000000, 
    50, 0.001042377962108}}`

And I have the question, how can I pull the graph in the Z axis by setting of other step of plotting?

Comment: Can you add some sample data to work with?  Just a few points will do.

Comment: I added datum to question.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the aspect ratio from the default, and added z-axis tick values.

You could simply use `Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 0.0002, 0.0004, 0.0006, 0.0008, 0.001}}` but I added some formatting.  `FindDivisions` is useful for less straightforward cases.

```
Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 10000, 10000000}, {y, 10, 50}, Mesh -> 15, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.0011}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {0.001, 0.0003}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7], 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesStyle -> {Black, Black, Black}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic,
    {#, NumberForm[#, {3, 4}]} & /@ N@FindDivisions[{0, 0.001}, 5]},
  AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 300], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[.016], Point[data]}]]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Adding sub-ticks:-

```
Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 10000, 10000000}, {y, 10, 50}, Mesh -> 15, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.0011}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {0.001, 0.0003}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7], 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesStyle -> {Black, Black, Black}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic,
    DeleteCases[
     Flatten[{{#1, NumberForm[#1, {3, 4}]}, {#2, ""}, {#3, ""}, {#4, ""}} & @@@
       Partition[N@FindDivisions[{0, 0.001}, 20], 4, 4, {1, 1}, Null], 1],
     {Null, _}]},
  AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 300], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[.016], Point[data]}]]
```

[image]

**Adding Box Ratios**

```
Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 10000, 10000000}, {y, 10, 50}, Mesh -> 15,
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.0011},
  PlotRangePadding -> {0.001, 0.0003}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7],
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesStyle -> {Black, Black, Black},
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic,
    DeleteCases[
     Flatten[{{#1, NumberForm[#1, {3, 4}]}, {#2, ""}, {#3, ""}, {#4, ""}} & @@@  
       Partition[N@FindDivisions[{0, 0.001}, 20], 4, 4, {1, 1}, Null], 1],
     {Null, _}]}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 1200],
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[.016], Point[data]}], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 3},
 BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 36]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks better, but I meant anyway, that I need to pull this field by setting up of the visual length for every step..Hmm..for example, between values 0.0002, 0.0004, 0.0006 (z axis) I need more pixels and It will pull my graph.

Comment: @yavalas - I'm guessing you mean adding sub-ticks.

Comment: Nope, I'm guessing, that I need more pixels between every tick( between values 0.0002, 0.0004, 0.0006 for example). And after it my graph will look bigger.

Comment: @yavalas - Maybe you just need to increase the image size, e.g. `ImageSize -> 900`?

Comment: No. By it looks better anyway. Thanks. I need pull by one z axis.

Comment: @yavalvas - How about box ratios? E.g. `Show[Plot3D[...], Graphics3D[...], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 3}]`